Tiling rectangles with I and T tetrominoes
I wonder which $m \times n$ rectangles can be tiled by $I$ (straight line of length $4$) and $T$ tetrominoes (rotations allowed). I am mostly looking for references, but any help is welcome.
So far, I know the following :
An $m \times n$ rectangle can be tiled by $I$ tetrominoes if and only if one of $m$ or $n$ is a multiple of $4$
One direction is trivial, for the other direction one can use a coloring by $\{1, 2, 3, 4\}$.
An $m \times n$ rectangle can be tiled by $T$ tetrominoes if and only if both m and n are multiples of 4.
One direction is trivial, the other one is due to Walkup
If an $m \times n$ rectangle can be tiled by $I$ and $T$ tetrominoes, then $mn$ is a multiple of $4$. So in view of the above, we only need to look at the case where both $m$ and $n$ are congruent to $2$ modulo $4$. It is easy to show that $2 \times (4k+2)$ is not doable. So the smallest next possibilities are $6 \times 6$ and $6 \times 10$. In both case, we can use :
If an $m \times n$ rectangle can be tiled by $I$ and $T$ tetrominoes and both $m$ and $n$ are even, then both the number of horizontal $T$ and the number of vertical $T$ are even.
To show this, color the rows (the column) alternatively in black and white.
If I believe this website https://polyominoes.org/data/4I+4T#title, $6 \times 6$ is not tileable, while $6 \times 10$ is. (Be aware that on the above website, tiling by $\{I,T\}$ means that at least one $I$ and one $T$ must be used.). However, the website provide no proof for the impossibility of $6 \times 6$ and the image for the $6 \times 10$ tiling is broken.
I tried some coloring arguments for $6 \times 6$ as well as to have a lucky guess for $6 \times 10$, but without any luck so far.

I think OP is asking for 2-3 things :
(A) Impossibility for $6 \times 6$
When we use one $I$ tetromino at a corner , we get $6 \times 5$ left over , with one $2 \times 1$ corner.
That corner either will require 2 $I$ tetrominoes (which will give a new $2 \times 1$ corner) or will require 1 $T$ tetromino with 1 $I$ tetromino.
Continuing that way , we will eventually run out without getting the Solution.
When we alternately use one $T$ at the corner , there are only a few ways to continue tiling , which will eventually run out without getting the Solution.
[[ Since there are only $9$ tiles ($6 \times 6 / 4 $) available , it is somewhat easy to check the Cases exhaustively ]]
Hence $6 \times 6$ is impossible.
(B) Solution for $6 \times 10$
The website gives this :

(C) Checking higher values
We can easily get $6 \times 14$ using $6 \times 10$ with $6 \times 4$
Attaching $4 \times 14$ will give $10 \times 14$
Attaching $4 \times 14$ twice will give $14 \times 14$
That way , we can easily add $4$ to either Direction to get the Solutions for $(n+4) \times (m)$ , $(n) \times (m+4)$ , $(n+4) \times (m+4)$ in terms of $(n) \times (m)$
We can thus always tile $(4n+2) \times (4m+2)$ , except for $6 \times 6$ which is impossible.

Thanks for the picture. I was not able to see it correctly. Apparently, something is wrong with my version of Firefox. However, I do not understand the proof for A. Using one I will not leave a 6 x5 left over.

Oh , I was thinking something else entirely when I wrongly wrote that ! Nice Catch , @PHL , I have rectified that now.

I had a similar proof for the impossibility of 6x6, depending on the position of an I in the rectangle (corner, side, middle). But then I used Walkup result to get ride of the all Ts cases. Your version is more direct. I hoped for something using colorings, but it is probably too much to ask for.

I think coloring approach is hard here. While $T$ has a "center" , which we can color to then count the total colorings , there is no "center" for the $I$ , hence coloring it will not be very easy ! We will have to check multiple ways to color , @PHL , ending up with more work !
